# Facebook Notes In Drupal

Tags: facebook, drupal

We have a public FB page and I would like to embed the notes section into a Drupal site, so when we post a new note about an event or something it shows on the Drupal site (I'd like to put it under a latest news type section).

Are there any Drupal modules (we're using Drupal 6) that would allow such functionality?

I've seen a few around that rely on RSS feeds but I believe Facebook are dropping RSS feeds. I see that I can browse to http://graph.facebook.com/OUR_ID/notes and possibly get a JSON feed of the data however it says the following:

"type": "OAuthException",
"message": "An access token is required to request this resource."

And I don't really know anything about JSON so I don't know what that means or how I could bring the data into the site. Has anyone achieved this before, and if so, how?

Comment: For questions about Drupal there is also drupal.stackexchange.com. Please visit us! **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, perhaps I was wrong. There is still an rss feed of the notes section;

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/notes.php?id=1234&viewer=1234&key=5678&format=rss20

I can pull this in so that will do :)